# How to make drag and drop component part of ul

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I got this component which looks like

```js
  draggable(:list="points")
    ul.bar.flex
```

I want my `li` list to be part of it, but it wont work unless i swap the draggable component with `ul`. In vue 2 there was option `tag="ul"` but in vue 3 it doesn't exist.. is there any way that I can apply this component on the `ul` element?

```js
li(v-for="(point, i) in points" :key="point.id" draggable="true")
        router-link(:to="{ name: 'Points', params: { id: point.id } }")
          .circle.bg-gray-500.grid.place-items-center
            p.text-white {{ i + 1 }}
          .cut-point-text
            | {{ point.name }}
```